# Rails 3.0.2 unescaping get request parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 applications one with rails 3.0.2 and one with 4.x.x . These applications have an action named redirect_now that takes a request with some parameters and redirects the user where the redirect_to parameters points to.

A request would look something like:

```
0.0.0.0:3000/redirect_now?param1=lala&param2=lala&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.germanos.ro%2Fapp%2Fsearch.do%3Faction%3DExecute%26searchString%3Dtelevizor%2Bsamsung%26x%3D0%26y%3D0
```

This request works fine in the 4.x.x rails app however in the 3.x.x rails app when I type request.url I get:
`http://0.0.0.0:3000/redirect_now?param1=lala&param2=lala&redirect_to=http://www.germanos.ro/app/search.do?action=Execute&searchString=televizor+samsung&x=0&y=0"` which obviously leads rails into thinking that there are 3 more parameters in the url searchString x, and y instead of using those parameters in the redirect url.

There are no filters or anything that could impact the get request. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post the `redirect_now` method.

Comment: it is blank :D def redirect_now end

Comment: it doesn't redirect i have a binding.pry there to see request.url which has that redirect_to parameter unescaped instead of the escaped version i delivered by hand .

Comment: i can't really post code since it is an application from work :(. I skipped all filters also to be sure there is no such thing that does this: 'skip_filter *_process_action_callbacks.map(&:filter)'

Comment: My main focus was some rack/ruby version/rails version thingy ...

Comment: I wouldn't be to surprised to learn that this is a bug in Rails 3.0.2. Did you consider upgrading the app? 3.0.2 was released more that 5 years ago. Even the latest 3.0 version (3.0.20) is unmaintained for for more than 3 years now. Your app will very likely be vulnerable to several security issues.

Comment: I see. Well we will use the 4.x.x app soon instead of the 3.x.x but in the meantine I wanted to solve this. Ok so no idea with what I provided no ?